# ArrayList elements replace with new entries

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm new in Java, and writing a small application in java using `ArrayList` of an object.

```
    Transaction trans= new Transaction();
    ArrayList<Transaction> arrTrans = new ArrayList<Transaction>();
```

When I `Debug` the application, I can see when I add new element to the arrayList **all** the previous elements of `arrTrans` are replaced with the new element.

```
private void add(Transaction trans){
    trans.description= (String)(jTextField1.getText());
    trans.type=(String) (jComboBox1.getSelectedItem());
    trans.amount=(String)(jTextField2.getText());
    trans.date=(String)(jTextField3.getText());
arrTrans.add(trans);
}
```

I thought ArrayList object adds new index for every new element that is gonna be added to the list and never modifies previous elements. What's wrong with my code?

Comment: put the `Transaction trans= new Transaction();` inside the add(). You need to create a new object everytime and add the newly created object with its values to the list. Also use setters and getters for the class variables. ie Instead of `trans.description= "somevalue"` , do `trans.setDescription("somevalue");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is this code

```
private void add(Transaction trans)
```

because you are passing an object and the setting the values of the object which replaces the previous value so do something like this

```
private void add(){
Transaction trans= new Transaction();
//then set whatever you want to the obect and add the object to the list
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comprehensive answer!

Comment: the first answer gave you most of it but I just tried to show you the exact reason of failure happy to help :)

Comment: Thanks for acknowledging that. I'm little little mystified as to why you were able to take away that accepted answer, but I'll be sportsmanlike about it: have a +1.

Comment: Take it easy guys! I appreciate either one of you for your help. I just tried to vote the answer which was the most comprehensive. :)

Answer (score 4):

You're always adding the same `Transaction` object and only update its contents. The previous elements are not replaced, they are in fact all the same element.

There is no automatic copy created of an object if you add it to an `ArrayList`. You have to instantiate a `new Transaction()` every time, populate its fields, and add it to the `ArrayList`.

Your code could look something like this:

```
private void add() {
    Transaction trans = new Transaction();
    trans.description = (String) jTextField1.getText();
    trans.type = (String) jComboBox1.getSelectedItem();
    trans.amount = (String) jTextField2.getText();
    trans.date = (String) jTextField3.getText();

    arrTrans.add(trans);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have just initiated an object when you use  **Transaction trans= new Transaction();** . And you have just modified the object created by you just now when you use  **private void add(Transaction trans){}** .
You said that you were new to java so that I advise you to read something about create objects and you can refer to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html